# JHipster resolve conflicts after upgrading an app

Tags: jhipster

for the first time I updated an app with the `jhipster upgrade` command.
It seems all ok but at the end of the updating it noticed me about three conflicts that I have to resolve manually.

My first problem is: how to update the Liquibase scripts?
In this case, have been added some `uniqueConstraintName` but I can't to add them in my scripts because they have already been executed.
So, which is the best solution? Don't update the scripts? Mark them as merged? Add manually another script in order to add these constraints?

[image]

And how I have to solve other conflicts like the image below?
Simply copy and paste from new file to old file?

[image]

Thanks a lot,
Andrea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a live database, then you must not upgrade your liquibase scripts but add new ones to do the migration. What you can do is running the new scripts against a blank dev database (same type of db as prod), then revert to old scripts, then call `./mvnw liquibase:diff` to get the delta script, then add the delta script to the scripts to run.